# Rate limit GET requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an external API that rate-limits API requests to up to 25 requests per second. I want to insert parts of the results into a MongoDB database.

How can I rate limit the request function so that I don't miss any of API results for all of the array?

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            //need to rate limit the following function, without missing any value in the arr array
            request( {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://SOME_API/json?address='+arr[i]
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                //doing computation, including inserting to mongo
            }
            )
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This could possibly be done using the `request-rate-limiter` package. So you can add this to your code :

```
var RateLimiter = require('request-rate-limiter');
const REQS_PER_MIN = 25 * 60; // that's 25 per second
var limiter = new RateLimiter(REQS_PER_MIN);
```

and since `request-rate-limiter` is based on `request` you can just replace `request` with `limiter.request`

You can find further information on the package's npm page - https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-rate-limiter

*On a personal note - I'd replace all these callbacks with promises*

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine 2 things.

- A throttling mechanism. I suggest [_.throttle](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle) from the lodash project. This can do the rate limiting for you.
- You also need an async control flow mechanism to make sure the requests run in series (don't start second one until first one is done). For that I suggest [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)

Both of these changes will be cleaner if you refactor your code to this signature:

```
function scrape(address, callback) {
   //code to fetch a single address, do computation, and save to mongo here
   //invoke the callback with (error, result) when done
}
```