# Using node to get data from a rate-limited API

Tags: node.js

I want to use node to get data from a rate-limited API. The API have limites on a per day and on a per month basis. I am having trouble finding an algorithm where the code knows how many of the api calls allowed on that minute/day have already been used.

I would like my logic to:

- rate limit the get requests (potential answer is here: [Rate limit GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783542/rate-limit-get-requests))
- switch keys when the API is close to the limit

Help!

My (pseudo)code looks like this:

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

keys = ['1a2a3a','2b1b2f']

function readData(a, b, key, cb) {

  var url = 'http://json.infoprovider.com/data.json?'
    + 'a=' + a
    + '&b=' + b
    + '&key=' + key

  unirest.get(url).end(function (response) {
    cb(response.body);
  })   
}

csv
.fromPath("data.csv", { headers: true })
.on("data", function (data) {

    readData(data.a, data.b, key[0], function (r) {
        console.log("a: " + data.a + ", lng: " + data.b + ", result: " + (JSON.stringify(r)));
        console.log("API consumed: " & r.UsedThisDay)
    })
})
```

Comment: *"I am having trouble finding an algorithm where the code knows how many of the api calls allowed on that minute/day"* An algorithm ? Why not just increment a counter for that minute/day ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`node-rate-limiter`](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter)

From their examples:

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
var limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 250);


limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
  callMyMessageSendingFunction(...);
});
```

Just add a counter in there, associate it with the day, and you have a way to rate limit yourself *as well as* limit the requests per day, if you do so choose.

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
var limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 250);
var requestsToday = 0; // Gets reset on each "new" day
var requestsLimitPerDay = 200;

limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
  callMyMessageSendingFunction(...);
});

function callMyMessageSendingFunction() {
    requestsToday++;
    if (requestsToday < requestsLimitPerDay) {
        makeAPICall();
    }
}
```

**I only suggest both, since if it has a limit per day, it probably has a limit per second/minute as well; in my experience.** It's better to throttle your requests all-around. A multi-core Nodejs app running on some massive server is a sure-fire way to anger a web service as it fires off concurrent web request after web request without regard.

---

You also have the option of calculating the requests limit per day, and using that as your `RateLimiter(1, x)` argument over the same of 24 hours, although you're not going to get your API calls back nearly as quick.

Comment: Thanks - that might work, but how would I make this work with the logic of reading an external CSV file (the reading of the file is asynchronous). My "MessageSending" function would have to read the next line of a csv.

Comment: That's really another question regarding file reading with Node.js. [It's built into Node though](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream). You'll also want to harness async-like functions so that you can wait for a function to complete before moving on. This is a common problem in Node. [Async works well for me](https://github.com/caolan/async).